# Git Windows acting funky

Tags: windows, git

I just freshly installed Git 2.5 on Windows 7 64 bit.  If I run:

```
git init
git add --all
```

On a local directory with a text file in it, `git init` succeeds (a .git folder is created).  But, the `git add --all` throws this error:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I want to add the text file to the repo.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.

** Possibly related:

If I right click on the git directory and run `Git GUI Here` I get the following error:

```
No working director C:\Program Files (x86)\Git:

couldn't change working directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git": no such file or directory
```

Git is installed in C:\Program Files\Git and my repo is in My Documents folder.

** EDIT

If I run `export GIT_WORK_TREE=./` everything works fine.  But I have to do this each time I open a shell window.  Anyway around this?

Comment: Exists the .git folder in your directory if not then its not a git repository.

Comment: This certainly isn't expected, nor can I reproduce it; what is `GIT_WORK_TREE` or `GIT_DIR` set to *before* you change it?  Anything?

Comment: No, both GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR aren't set to anything.